# MLE for mean of a normal distribution given the range of the mean

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

If $X \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu,1)$ and $\mu \in (-m,m)$ where $0<m<1$ is a known constant. Then how can I work out the MLE of $\mu$ in this case?

I know in the case where $\mu$ is completely unknown, then the MLE $\hat{\mu} (X)$ is just $X$. However, I really need some insights into how to take into account the given range of $\mu$. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to allow $\mu\in[-m,m]$ instead.

Comment: If $X$ is outside the interval, then the likelihood is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, making the point of maximum likelihood obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments we will allow $\mu \in [-m,m]$ rather than $(-m,m)$. The likelihood function is
$$L(\mu)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}),$$
so maximizing the likelihood function is equivalent to minimizing the distance
$$|x-\mu|.$$
If $x> m$, then the distance is minimized by $\hat{\mu} = m$ and if $x< -m$, then the distance is minimized by $\hat{\mu} = -m$, thus the maximum likelihood estimator is given by:
$$\hat{\mu} := \begin{cases} -m & X < -m \\ X & X \in [-m,m] \\ m & X > m \end{cases}$$

Remark: If we only allow $\mu \in (-m,m)$, then the MLE is technically undefined for $X \in (-\infty,-m] \cup [m,\infty)$, that is why we should consider $\mu \in [-m,m]$ instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: Sorry to ask you again but do you have any idea on how to prove that this estimator is inadmissible under square loss?

Comment: This seems more like an entirely new question than a supplementary question.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood of $\mu$ outside the range you specified is 0. Accordingly, the MLE is the same as in the usual case except truncated to the range you've specified.